# How to dynamically set header value in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, header, http-headers, jstl

I have a JSP file which creates an Excel document.

I want to dynamically set the name of the file to be downloaded.

This is how I set the file name to "test.xsl":

```
<% response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel"); 
   response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=" + "test.xsl" ); 
%>
```

How can I set the file name to be test-${today's date}.xsl ( i.e. test-20100805.xsl ) ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
String fname = MessageFormat.format( 
    "test-{0,date,yyyyMMdd}.xsl", new Object [] { new Date() } );
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=" + fname );
```

I think this should work for you.

The text in the braces tells the `MessageFormat` class to insert value `0` from the given array, format it as a `date` using the format `yyyyMMdd` (e.g. `20161231` for Dec 31st 2016).

Comment: Ah, just needed to remove the spaces inside the {braces}:

test-{0,date,yyyyMMdd}.xsl

Comment: Oops.  Sorry, my fault for trying to make it more readable.  :-)