# Download html content loaded inside iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, iframe

I have an iframe which displays an HTML page. There's an ajax call to server which creates the HTML file and returns the path to file as a response, to which I dynamically create iframe and display it.

Now, I need to know, is there a way I can allow user to download that HTML file from that iframe? May be a button which when clicked, does the downloading.

How can i extract that? Sorry if the question is not framed correctly. I am trying my best.
Below is the code to display the HTML file

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'diffReport?url='+url,
    success:function(data){
        var div = document.getElementById("diffReport");
        div.innerHTML = '<iframe style="width:100%;height:100%;" frameborder="0" src="'+data+'" />';
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

After the ajax call to a servlet, a physical HTML file is created within the server directory. Now am not able to understand how to give user/client the liberty to download that file to his local system.

Please suggest.

Comment: Could you just add a "right-click to save" link, with the same href as the frame src?

Comment: A quick and perfect reply. Thanks!

Comment: But 'right-click to save' link doesn't saves the complete webpage. The css are left behind. Infact, opening the link in another window (target="_blank" attribute) and then saving from the browser will do the trick

Answer (score 0):

To download file you need to perform full postback to the server. Since you are using ajax you can achieve this (in theory - I have not tested it tough) by pointing the src attribute of your iframe to the url which in turn will return the html in response with modified header: "application/octet-stream". Thats generally the idea. The implementation will depend on server side environment you're using.

Comment: I am using java for server side. I guess providing the anchor tag and pointing the 'href' to iframe source would do the trick. But for that, user had to right click and save page. Is there a way to download the complete source on just a click ? I am interested in that.

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3417895/how-to-dynamically-set-header-value-in-jsp) you can find information how to modify the header in JSP. You can add a parameter to the url like: "?file=download" and depending on that serve the file with modified header or not.

Comment: No, this didn't helped. The file is being downloaded but any external css and js used are not downloaded with it.